# Basic assembly in mov function pointers

Tags: pointers, assembly, mov

I want to put a new value into a pointer (in the value that he point of him) but I fail.

The program push to the stack

```
offset result, num1 and num2
```

The maximize need to be in result...

Now I need your help

```
org  100h

jmp main

    result      dw ?
    num0        dw ?
    num1        dw ?


main:  
    mov bp,sp     
    push (offset result) 
    push num0 
    push num1
    call max
    MOV AX,num0
    call print_num
    PRINTN
    MOV AX,num1
    call print_num
    PRINTN
    MOV AX,result
    call print_num
    PRINTN 
    ret

max PROC

    push bp        
    mov bp,sp
    MOV AX,[BP+6]
    MOV BX,[BP+4]
    MOV CX,[BP+2]
    CMP AX,BX
    JGE BIG
    MOV [CX],BX 
BIG:
    MOV [CX],AX  
    mov sp,bp
    pop bp
    ret

max ENDP


include magshimim.inc \\our program built for us defines for the inputs...
```

I want to do:

```
MOV [CX] , AX
```

but the emu8086 doesn't really like me :)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problems found:

- "push (offset result)" seems to store the wrong value because of the parenthesis.
- As soon as procedure "max" begins, BP is pushed on stack, so the parameters are no longer in BP+6, +4 and +2, they are in BP+8, +6 and +4.
- "[CX]" can't be used as pointer, let's change it by BX.
- It is necessary to skip label "BIG" in case CX is greater.

Here is the code with the little fixes :

```
org  100h

jmp main

    result      dw ?
    num0        dw 5    ;VALUE TO TEST.
    num1        dw 2    ;VALUE TO TEST.


main:  
    mov bp,sp     
    push offset result  ;PARENTHESIS SEEM TO STORE THE WRONG VALUE.
    push num0 
    push num1
    call max
    MOV AX,num0
    call print_num
    PRINTN
    MOV AX,num1
    call print_num
    PRINTN
    MOV AX,result
    call print_num
    PRINTN 
    ret

max PROC

    push bp         ;"BP" IN STACK. PARAMTERS ARE NO LONGER IN BP+6,+4,+2.
    mov bp,sp

    MOV BX,[BP+8]   ;BX = RESULT'S ADDRESS.
    MOV AX,[BP+6]   ;AX = NUM0'S VALUE.
    MOV CX,[BP+4]   ;CX = NUM1'S VALUE.
    CMP AX,CX
    JGE BIG
    MOV [BX],CX 
    jmp finish      ;NECESSARY TO SKIP "BIG".
BIG:
    MOV [BX],AX  
;    mov sp,bp
finish:
    pop bp
    ret

max ENDP
```